# Python signals for multiprocessing

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, signals

I would like to execute a certain signal handler in a multi-threading python program.
I noted that my signal handler is called for main thread and the other thread (thread_1) that I have created.
Is there any way to execute the signal handler only for thread_1?
Or is there any way to know the thread ID of the thread that calls the signal handler? Is it the main thread or thread_1?

```
import signal
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep
x = 3;

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name
    while(1):
        sleep (1)
        print "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global x
    print 'You pressed Ctrl+C!'
    print x
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    print 'Creating thread'
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    print 'Press Ctrl+C'
    x += 6
    signal.pause()
    print 'After press CTRL+C'
```

Got an output:

```
Creating thread
Press Ctrl+C
hello bob
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
^CYou pressed Ctrl+C!
You pressed Ctrl+C!
9
3
```

As you can signal handler is called twice (one for main thread and another for thread_1), and as I asked above, I would like to execute handler only for thread_1 or even find a way to get thread_id of the calling thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal is handled in two separate *processes* rather than two distinct *threads* of a single process.  (Hint:  you `import multiprocessing` rather than `import threading`.)

The child process inherits the signal handler for SIGINT and gets its own copy of `x`.  Now, the shell runs both your parent and child processes in a foreground process group, and sends keyboard-generated signals (like Ctrl-C => SIGINT) to the whole process group, which is why both parent and child receive the signal.  Both parent and child, then, print their own value of `x`.

If you do switch to a threaded implementation, then [only the main thread](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) will receive signals, and your question will be moot.